# How to make scrollbar of inner element visible on the outer element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At our work interface there is an *ugly* table structure that is generated for viewing potentially very large outputs of queries. Warning, I have very little web dev experience.

It looks something like this:

```
<div class = "view_scroll_outer">
        <table class = "scrollTableHeader" ...>
        <div class = "view_scroll_inner" ...>
            <table ...>
                  ... stuff in here
        <table class = "scrollTableFooter" ...>
```

A) `ScrollTableHeader` table contains the columns of the final visible table with the data.

B) The table in the inner `<div>` element contains the rows of the final table (with the data).

I can't change this structure right now - that will have to wait for another month. But this structure has some problems. I took care of a number of them for now but this particular one is really bugging me.

Let's suppose that the data is very wide (aka a lot of columns and a lot of rows). This causes problems in that the columns will be under the outer `<div>` element so the horizontal scrollbar will have to show up on the outer. BUT the vertical scrollbar will be showing up in the inner because the rows containing the data are in the inner one.
This results in users having to scroll all the way to the right on the outer table before they can see the vertical scroll box for the inner box.

Here is what I've tried:

1) Change the width of the inner div box

```
document.getElementsByClassName('view_scroll_inner')[0].style.width = (visWidth * 0.99) +'px'; //visWidth is the width of the visual area
```

This ends up just cutting the columns past the visual area

2) Change the width of the outer div box

```
document.getElementsByClassName('view_scroll_outer')[0].style.width = (visWidth * 0.99) +'px';
```

This essentially ended doing the same thing.

At this point the only other possible solution to this that comes to my mind (apart from nuking this and rewriting it, which I will in a month) would be to somehow find a vertical scrollbar that *stays on the right end of what you're seeing, not the right end of the actual window*. This way, as you're scrolling horizontally on the outer box, the scrollbar would follow along the right side of the visible box.

Does anyone know of any scrollbars like that? Or does anyone know of any other potential solutions to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use external type of [jQuery Scrollbar](http://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) and place scrollbar in any element on a page. Look at advanced scrollbars demo.